# How to use Taylor Series expansion to derive the finite difference discretization?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

Given nodal points of i-1, i, i+1 and i+2 , we want to derive the finite difference discretization for (dy/dx)i . Hint: would be good to establish a statement stating the
representation of (dy/dx)i at the above-mentioned nodal points on the LHS and equating
to the order of the representation on the RHS, and hence a table with the appropriate
Taylor series expansions equating the LHS = RHS.)

Subsequently, I need to obtain the order of accuracy for the derived finite difference operator, question is where can I start?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4109353/418542.)

Comment: similar but different context?