# Derivative estimation on non-standard stencil $j-1, \dots, j+2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

Let's say I want to obtain the finite difference representation of the differential operator $(dU/dx)_j$ at the nodal point $j$ (or $j\Delta x$). I'm also interested in the mentioned finite difference operator at the
nodal points at $(j-1)$, $j$, $(j+1)$ and $(j+2)$, which is not symmetrical about the nodal point $j$. This
is because I want to implement the boundary conditions involving $(dU/dx)_j$ at the
boundary in which a symmetrical finite difference representation would create additional
fictitious nodal points outside the computational domain of interest. So, in the derivation, I want to
obtain the finite difference operator of $(dU/dx)_j$ at the nodal points at $(j-1)$, $j$, $(j+1)$ and $(j+2)$,
also determine the order of accuracy of the representation.

What are some of the simple ways of obtaining the finite difference representation aside from Implicit Runge Kutta method?

Comment: For common stencils (forward, backward, central), you might have a look at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), but the same methodology can be used for less common stencils. Could you please show what you have tried?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/km4o87m